# Dynamics CRM 2013 SetParameter Out of Stack Space

Tags: dynamics-crm-2013

I have used similar code to load grids with custom FetchXML but I can't get this one working.  I get a Out of Stack space error.  I have tried to change up the timer but that hasn't helped.  Has something changed in CRM I'm not aware of?

function UpdateSubGridRelatedMatters() {

```
    var grid = document.getElementById("RelatedMTIGrid");

    //If this method is called from the form OnLoad, make sure that the grid is loaded before proceeding 
    //Included extra null check as a rollup 5 fix 


    var relatedMatterID = Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get("sage_relatedmatter").getValue()[0].id;

    //if (relatedMatterID != null) {
        //Update the fetchXML that will be used by the grid.  
        var fetchXml = "";
        fetchXml += "<fetch version=\" 1.0\"  output-format=\" xml-platform\"  mapping=\" logical\"  distinct=\" false\" >";
        fetchXml += "<attribute name=\" sage_mtiid\"  />";
        fetchXml += "<attribute name=\" sage_name\"  />";
        fetchXml += "<attribute name=\" createdon\"  />";
        fetchXml += "<attribute name=\" sage_scientistisconsultant\"  />";
        fetchXml += "<attribute name=\" sage_secondlab\"  />";
        fetchXml += "<attribute name=\" sage_scientisthascfn\"  />";
        fetchXml += "<attribute name=\" sage_scientist\"  />";
        fetchXml += "<attribute name=\" sage_redlines\"  />";
        fetchXml += "<attribute name=\" sage_providermatterid\"  />";
        fetchXml += "<attribute name=\" sage_organizationcontact\"  />";
        fetchXml += "<attribute name=\" sage_organization\"  />";
        fetchXml += "<attribute name=\" sage_matterid\"  />";
        fetchXml += "<attribute name=\" sage_origin\"  />";
        fetchXml += "<attribute name=\" sage_materialtype\"  />";
        fetchXml += "<attribute name=\" sage_hostmatterid\"  />";
        fetchXml += "<attribute name=\" sage_hostcontact\"  />";
        fetchXml += "<attribute name=\" sage_host\"  />";
        fetchXml += "<attribute name=\" sage_executedbyhhmi\"  />";
        fetchXml += "<attribute name=\" createdby\"  />";
        fetchXml += "<order attribute=\" createdon\"  descending=\" false\"  />";
        fetchXml += "<order attribute=\" sage_name\"  descending=\" false\"  />";
        fetchXml += "<filter type=\"  and\" >";
        fetchXml += "<condition attribute=\" sage_relatedmtiid\"  operator=\" eq\"  value=\" " + relatedMatterID + "\"  />";
        fetchXml += "</filter>";
        fetchXml += "</entity>";
        fetchXml += "</fetch>";


        if (grid == null || grid.readyState != "complete") {
            //The subgrid hasn't loaded, wait 1 second and then try again     
            setTimeout(UpdateSubGridRelatedMatters(), 3000);
            return;
        }

        debugger;
        //Inject the new fetchXml  
        grid.control.SetParameter("fetchXml", fetchXml);

        //Force the subgrid to refresh  
        grid.control.refresh();

   // }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling UpdateSubGridRelatedMatters and passing the result rather than the function itself as a parameter to setTimeout which puts you into a recursive loop hence the stackoverflow.

Change

```
setTimeout(UpdateSubGridRelatedMatters(), 3000);
```

To

```
setTimeout(UpdateSubGridRelatedMatters, 3000);
```